# Spring Cloud Stream access to raw Stream

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-reactive

Here is my use case, user subscribe to my stream using websocket (GraphQl with subscription), I need to return an instance of `org.reactivestreams.Publisher` (which should be my kafka topic subscription) filtering message by user id.

To illustrate, something like this:

```
/ **
  *  I don´t know how to get a instance of Publisher<Balance>
  *  It should be a consumer from a kafka topic
  */
fun balance(myStream: Publisher<Balance>, userId: String): Publisher<Balance> {
    return myStream.filter { it.userId == userId }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to write a Spring Cloud Stream consumer and then publish it to WebSocket programmatically. Something along the lines of

```
public Consumer<Flux<Balance>> myStream() {

  //filter here and then publish to websocket.

}
```

[Here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/websocket/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/websocket/sink/WebsocketSinkConfiguration.java#L88) is an example of a WebSocket sink implementation that you can potentially use as a guide, but this is not reactive.